# Exchange 2007 OWA returns blank page with url xxxxx&reason=0

Tags: exchange-2007

I've just run into an issue with my exchange OWA.  It returns a blank page with the url string https://www.xxxxxxxx/&reason=0.

Nothing in the logs gives me any good reasons.

Here's what I've done so far;
1) reinstall Exchange roll-up 7.
2) recreate virtual directories.
3) reboot.  (this was mostly a shot in the dark, but what the hell)

Exchange via rpc/https is still working great.

Anyone run into this before?

EDIT
Here is the last snippet from the OWASetupLog.  doesn't look like anything blew up.

[09:45:36] ***********************************************
[09:45:36] * UpdateOwa.ps1: 5/27/2009 9:45:36 AM
[09:45:40] Updating OWA on server HOMER
[09:45:40] Finding OWA install path on the filesystem
[09:45:40] Updating OWA to version 8.1.375.2
[09:45:40] Copying files from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\owa\Current' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\owa\8.1.375.2'
[09:45:41] Getting all Exchange 2007 OWA virtual directories
[09:45:42] Found 1 OWA virtual directories.
[09:45:42] Updating OWA virtual directories
[09:45:42] Processing virtual directory with metabase path 'IIS://HOMER.DG.LOCAL/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa'.
[09:45:42] Metabase entry 'IIS://HOMER.DG.LOCAL/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa/8.1.375.2' exists. Removing it.
[09:45:42] Creating metabase entry IIS://HOMER.DG.LOCAL/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa/8.1.375.2.
[09:45:42] Configuring metabase entry 'IIS://HOMER.DG.LOCAL/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa/8.1.375.2'.
[09:45:43] Saving changes to 'IIS://HOMER.DG.LOCAL/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa/8.1.375.2'
[09:45:43] Saving changes to 'IIS://HOMER.DG.LOCAL/W3SVC/1/ROOT/owa'

Comment: Still having problems with it.  Have removed all rollups, and then reinstalled latest (8), rebooted, cleaned out exchangesetuplogs folder and reinstalled rollup.  Still has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open Exchange Management Shell and run updateowa.ps1. [How to remove and to reinstall IIS on a computer that is running Exchange Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320202) might also help.

Comment: Unfortunately this one was too late for me.  I ended up redoing the server and that fixed it:-\

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually related to a roll-up install.

Can you check the Logs at %systemdrive%\ExchangeSetupLogs\UpdateOwa.log to see if there is anything in there indicating an error.

This error can also occur if the ExchangeSetupLogs folder is missing from the root of the system drive during setup. If it is, restore the folder and install the rollup again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Exchange 2007 SP3 Roll Up 5.

Everything ok bar OWA login.aspx page images it seems.

Blank page in IE8 , error icon bottom left of window.

Chrome loads the login.aspx with no images , app logs in ok and operates as expected to date.

Looking at:
C:\ExchangeSetupLogs\UpdateOWA.txt
[10:36:08] Getting all Exchange 2007 OWA virtual directories
[10:36:09] There are no Exchange 2007 OWA virtual directories.  Aborting.

I tried copying files from various DIRs into:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\Owa\8.3.213.0
from other versions. No joy.

Running uninstall of the roll up patch now. Will apply it again. After uninstall everything worked as expected again.

FOUND THIS:

"  Outlook Web Access Customizations
When you apply a service pack or an update rollup package, the update process may update the Logon.aspx file. If you have modified the Logon.aspx file, the file cannot be updated successfully. Therefore, Microsoft Office Outlook Web Access may not be updated correctly. In this scenario, after the update process is finished, Outlook Web Access may display a blank page.

To work around this issue, rename the Logon.aspx file before you apply the service pack or update rollup. Then, after you apply the update, you must re-create the Outlook Web Access customizations in the Logon.aspx file.

We recommend that you make a backup copy of any customized Outlook Web Access files before you apply a service pack or update rollup. For more information about Outlook Web Access customization details, see Introduction to Outlook Web App Customization.

For more information about how to create Outlook Web Access themes, see How to Create a Theme for Outlook Web Access."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221147(EXCHG.80).aspx

That should sort me out.